# MySQL query fetching different data than expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL, I have a table mtn_extract_list_email where there are columns called company,office,email,country and rating

I dont want emails that have domains aol , gmail, google

the query I am using is

```
select email from mtn_extract_list_email where (company like '%XYZ%' or office like '%XYZ%')
and (email not like '%@aol%' or email not like '%@gmail%' or email not like '%@google%')
and (Country = 'USA' and rating like 'A%')  
and email is not null;
```

this query fetches data but i noticed that it also fetched one email with @gmail as domain. I tried adjusting "AND" and "or" logic but still no luck. please guide what is wrong with my query.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the actual problem you're having. *Query not working How'd I like* will have absolutely no meaning if it turns up in a search result for a future user of this site. Your title should actually be descriptive; it's clear your query isn't working as you'd like, or you wouldn't be posting a question here.

Comment: You don't want domains in aol, AND you don't want gmail, AND you don't wan't google. The problem is that your query uses `OR`.

Comment: (email not like '%@aol%' AND email not like '%@gmail%' AND email not like '%@google%')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using or instead of and.

```
select email from mtn_extract_list_email 
        where (company like '%XYZ%' or office like '%XYZ%')
        (email not like '%@aol%' AND email not like '%@gmail%' AND email not like '%@google%')
        and (Country = 'USA' and rating like 'A%')  
        and email is not null;
```